# Adding GRID in WIX Installer

Tags: installation, wix, grid, wix3.5

I want to keep GRID or table in one of the screen in WIX installer listing some data.

Is there any property in WIX which will allow me to do so?

I want something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Windows Installer. It can be done only through custom dialogs drawn by an external UI.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by combination of custom action and win form.

1. Create C# Custom action project
2. Add Window form in the Project
3. Pass necessary information from wix to custom action
4. in custom action Open This window form as Dialog window and use the window application component.

I have done this in my project. i was used the tab control